# selenium dynamic growing table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have some troubles to handle dynamic growing table with selenium.
To sum up quickly, on my web app I have a table with 30 items  but it only displays the twenty first items and we have to scroll down to display the rest.
And I don't know how to get the 26th (for example) items without scrolling down.

My HTML:

```
<table id="tableID" tabindex="0" aria-multiselectable="true" role="grid">
    <thead>
    <tbody id="tableID-tblBody">
        <tr id="item1" role="row" tabindex="-1">
        <tr id="item2" role="row" tabindex="-1">
        [... 17 more]
        <tr id="item20" role="row" tabindex="-1">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After scrolling:

```
<table id="tableID" tabindex="0" aria-multiselectable="true" role="grid">
    <thead>
    <tbody id="tableID-tblBody">
        <tr id="item1" role="row" tabindex="-1">
        <tr id="item2" role="row" tabindex="-1">
        [... 27 more]
        <tr id="item30" role="row" tabindex="-1">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If someone could help me it would be great ^^
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would *[scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the last row in the table* (if necessary multiple times until you get the desired row count). For this I'd use `scrollIntoView()` via `executeScript()`:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

where `element`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id = 'tableID']//tr[last()]")).
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant get that item without scrolling down (to scroll down use @alecxe solution), because the element you want to choose is not even in the html at the time you search for it.
After the scroll you should be able to find it easily by id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to compare values

> Expected Value V/s Actual Value.

To do this I would request you to take all elements/object under this table : tableID-tblBody and search for ID of 26 and take value.

Here is my code that I used to perform similar task.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
            List<WebElement> totalrow  =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("tableID-tblBody"));

        for (int i = 0; i <= totalrow.size(); i++) {

            String xPath ="" //"XPATH OF 26 ITEM";

            try {

                WebElement element = ExpectedBehaviors
                        .expectPresenceofElementBy(driver, By.xpath(xPath),
                                getAlertTimeout());

                if (element.getText().trim().equals("EXPECTED VALUE")) {

                    //"PERFORM YOUR ACTION"                     
                    break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //"You can add your exception and error message

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but as @Piotroslav said, I cannot get the item "26" without scrolling down because the element is not on the DOM yet ^^

Comment: You are trying to take item 26 from front side or taking all object of table and searching for item 26 ? Above code will do option 2

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to take from the front side but even if I'm taking all object of the table, it still take the 20 first :(

Comment: You marked that javascript executor works for you ? If Yes than its ok else I will try to add more logic for you..