# How to scroll a div that is not an iframe in selenium?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to count my Facebook messages with friends, using Selenium Webdriver.

The messenger window has a frame containing the messages, but it must be scrolled to the start of the message history for all of the messages to be counted. My issue is with selecting that frame.

Upon inspecting the element, it notes that it is a `<div>`, which does not have a frame tag (`<iframe>`). Thus `driver_switch_to.frame()` does not work.

Another suggestion was to `driver_switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("js_1"))`, or something of the like, but this also did not work.

I'm having trouble on both facebook.com/messages and messenger.com, but a solution for either would be greatly appreciated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using their official API?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them according to their Facebook Terms of Service and Facebook Platform Policy. Just use the API

Comment: Seems like a similar question to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594712/selenium-dynamic-growing-table